# RxJava Single/Observable return implementation of interface

Tags: java, generics, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I have faced with interesting problem

I have the following method

```
@Override
public Single<IResults> getResults() {
    return Single.just(new ConcreteResults());
}
```

**IResults** is an interface and **ConcreteResults** is the implementation.

However I am getting an error

```
Error:(149, 27) error: incompatible types: Single<ConcreteResults> cannot be converted to Single<IResults>
```

How to solve this issue ? I need to have an interface to abstract return type.

However, this dirty trick seems to work :)

```
Single.just(new ConcreteResults())
                .map(new Function<ConcreteResults, IResults>() {
                    @Override
                    public IResults apply(@NonNull ConcreteResults results) throws Exception {
                        return results;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
@Override public Single<? extends IResults> getResults() { 
    return Single.just(new ConcreteResults()); 
}
```

Please remember that hieritance with genetics is a bit different.

Although IResults is a sub type of ConcreteResults, Single of ConcreteResults  is NOT a sub type of Single of IResults . You need to use a wildcard to create a relationship between then

You can search for more information about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a variable before returning the value. The compiler will figure out, that IResult is the over-type of ConcretResult. If you return it immediately the compiler does not get it.

```
@Test
void name() {
    Single<IResult> result = getResult();
}

private Single<IResult> getResult() {
    Single<IResult> just = Single.just(new Result());

    return just;
}

interface IResult {

}

class Result implements IResult {

}
```

For 1_7 Settings you must use:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

You have to give the compiler pointers, because in 1_7 the compiler does not inference the type from definition.

```
private Single<IResult> getResult() {
    Single<IResult> just = Single.<IResult>just(new Result());

    return just;
}
```

Comment: Which compiler-setup are you using? Did you try Single<IResult>.just(new Result());

Comment: I am using the default compiler bundled with Android Studio. This doesn't work as well

Comment: Which RxJava version are you using?

Comment: The latest RxJava2 version